# SVG filter not work with marker-end in Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, d3.js, svg

I have following svg code works great in Chrome, but the marker did not show in Firefox. Is there someone know why? Thanks!

```
<svg id="exhibition_svg" width="1235" height="487" class="exhibitionSvg"
  viewBox="-139.2135523613963,-60,806.4271047227926,318"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <defs>
    <filter id="bgPoint" width="800%" height="800%" x="-200%" y="-200%">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" width="800%" height="800%" x="-300%" 
        y="-300%">
      </feGaussianBlur>
    </filter>

    <marker id="app5end-arrow-active" viewBox="0 0 14 14" refX="7" refY="7"
      markerWidth="3" markerHeight="3" orient="auto" filter="url(#bgPoint)">
      <g>
        <circle cx="7" cy="7" r="5" fill="#122C34" stroke="#3AD5C9" stroke-width="1">
        </circle>
        <circle cx="7" cy="7" r="2" fill="#122C34" stroke="#3AD5C9" stroke-width="2">
        </circle>
      </g>
    </marker>

  </defs>

  <g>
    <path class="connect_line" d="M245,153L250,153L283,153L283,153"
      stroke="#0F364B" fill="none" stroke-width="7" rotate="auto"
      marker-end="url(#app5end-arrow-active)"
      marker-start="url(#app5end-arrow-active)">
    </path>
  </g>

</svg>
```

I also put it on codepen: https://codepen.io/rrandom/pen/yXrRZQ , please have a look

Comment: Firefox version: 54.0.1, Chrome version: 59.0.3071.115, both on win10(64bit)

Comment: Would you mind to reformat your source code, so the horizontal scrollbar will disappear?

Comment: @reporter done, thanks